# how to access activity button on dialog

Tags: android

I have an activity having 5 buttons. I called a custom dialog from button clicking on this activity. A list of dialog is opened and i am selecting an item and get back to that activity. Here I want to hide 3 buttons when I am returning from dialog. I can't restart activity from dialog.Anyone is there who helps Me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: add some code to improve your post

Comment: can you post your custom dialog code.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple.. Hide your 3 button on button click of custom dialog..

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog();
.//Your dialog code.
.
.
.
Button btn; // your custom dialog's button
btn = (Button)customdialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Hide your three main button here
            }
        });
```

Comment: I want to hide activity buttons.., Not dialog buttons. I mean as I click on dialog buttons, activities buttons should be hide...!!!

Comment: yes u can hide here ... btn1.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE); here btn1 is activity btn not dialog

Comment: Sorry dear... But I am creating my dialog in a different class. that's why I am facing a problem. Custom dialog is a different class not an inner class of activity. So the line, btn = (Button)customdialog.findViewById(R.id.button); not works I think.?

Comment: then u can pass your class reff in custom dialog & called one method of activity and put code of hide in method

Comment: I have done it but while I am using context.hideButtonMethod() in dialog code, it returns null pointer. Keep in mind, all the buttons working fine before dialog So there is not an error in findViewById() method I think?

Answer (score 1):

You can have callbacks on the dialogs which return some info (in your case the selected item in your activity).

did you see the multiple selection dialog here?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

After you have created that interface for the dialog result is just a matter of changing the visibility of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

the dialog is running from your `Activity` and not as a autonomis unit.

you can access local variables and change them.

what you can do is: from within the dialog, set the visibility of the 3 buttons to `View.INVISIBLE`

```
public void onClick(View v){
    button1.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
    button2.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
    button3.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I want to hide activity buttons.., Not dialog buttons. I mean as I click on dialog buttons, activities buttons should be hide...!!!

Comment: just rename the objects to the ones you want to hide

Comment: I have my dialog in different class not as the activity's inner class

Comment: if you want to show a `dialog` you have to pass it the context of the activity within it is shown. therefor you can always find anything with `context.findViewById()` if you say dialog but mean activity, use `Intent.putExtra`